# SSRS 2012 los reportes no muestran nada pero se exporta correctamente

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssrs

Tengo un problema bastante extraño al que no encuentro respuesta en internet.
Tengo una instalación de Reporting Services 2012 en la que los reportes tras ejecutar no muestan nada salvo la barra superior con los controles para cambiar de pagina, exportar, etc.

Aunque los reportes no muestran nada si selecciono exportar a cualquier formato el reporte se exporta correctamente con todo el contenido y datos que debería mostrar por pantalla.

Los reportes tienen pocos parametros los cuales en ningún caso tiene asociada una lista de valores posibles y tienen un unico valor por defecto para todos los parametros.

¿Alguna idea de que puede estar pasando?, lo unico que se me ocurre es reinstalar el servicio de reporting.

Desde el editor de reportes en Visual Studio los reportes funcionan bien.

Comment: ¿Sucede con todos los navegadores?

Comment: Si, con todos los que tengo instalados (IE 11, FF, Chrome y Opera)

Comment: Solucionado reinstalando SSRS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema desaparecio tras reinstalar el SSRS